# Codeigniter: Where to put the variable from a url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a stats site in Codeigniter locally. I have a url like localhost/sitename/player/show_profile/PlayerName

I currently have the following:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Player extends CI_Controller
{

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('player_model');
    $player_name = $this->uri->segment(3);
  }


  public function index()
  {
        echo "index";
  }

  public function show_profile($player_name)

  {

        $data['player_stats'] = $this->player_model->get_stats( $player_name );
        $this->load->view('player/player_stats', $data);
  }

}

?>
```

This works, but my question is regarding the $player_name variable. I have     `$player_name = $this->uri->segment(3);` in the __construct so it's available to all of the class methods. Is this the way I should be doing it?

Is this safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fist of all, there is no point in assigning the variable in the constructor because it's going to get overwritten. When you pass CI a url like localhost/sitename/player/show_profile/PlayerName, anything passed the method (i.e. PlayerName) get's set as the parameters. Therefore, your variable in

```
public function show_profile($player_name){
```

is already set when you get to your method code.

Secondly, I agree with Peter's:

```
protected $player_name;
```

for making it globally accessible in the controller. BUT, I don't agree with setting it in the constructor. If you have another method in this controller that passes a variable in that spot, you're going to get the wrong data in there. Set it in the method you called:

```
public function show_profile($player_name){

    $this->player_name = $player_name;

    $data['player_stats'] = $this->player_model->get_stats( $player_name );
    $this->load->view('player/player_stats', $data);
}
```

Comment: What about the `$this->uri->segment(3);` though?

Comment: I've updated my post. You don't need it if you stick to your original method prototype

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that CI passed those to the method. Good to know! Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. Here's the CI Docs on it: [CI Controllers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) Check the section Passing URI Segments to your Functions

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is define a class variable called $player_name and in the constructor set this to segment(3).

```
class Player extends CI_Controller
```

{

```
protected $player_name;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model( 'player_model' );
    $this->player_name = $this->uri->segment( 3 );
}

public function index() {
    echo "index";
}

public function ( show_profile ) {

    $data['player_stats'] = $this->player_model->get_stats( $this->player_name );
    $this->load->view( 'player/player_stats', $data );
}
```

}

This way will be able to access the $play_name variable anywhere in the class.

You could also check to see if it's set using the $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n) method and check to see if the key/value isset() **http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html**.

Peter